# I need to send two long variable to the other activity

Tags: android

I am using intent to call activity here and I need to send to long variable to the other activity.

Porjct.java

```
  Intent i = new Intent(ProjectList.this,RoleList.class);
  Bundle c = new Bundle();            
  c.putLong("PID", projectID );
  c.putLong("CTSID", castingTimeSlotID);
  i.putExtras(c);
  startActivityForResult(i,0);
  finish();
```

RoleList.java

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {    
            Bundle c = new Bundle();
        c = data.getExtras();
    projectID = b.getLong("PID");
    castingTimeSlotID = b.getLong("CTSID");}
```

This is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

The `onActivityResult()` should be in ProjectList.java - it will be called when your child Activity returns.

Your child Activity in RoleList.java should retrieve the data sent by the parent from the Bundle passed via `onCreate()`

If this is a little confusing; I suggest you read this first: http://www.remwebdevelopment.com/dev/a33/Passing-Bundles-Around-Activities.html - the example in there is very complete and they explain it better than I do. Notice how they pass data with key "mykey" from the parent Activity to the child; this is what you want to do.

---

Previous useless answer of mine follows

I think you don't need to retrieve the extras via a Bundle. Try this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {    
    projectID = data.getLongExtra("PID");
    castingTimeSlotID = data.getLongExtra("CTSID");
}
```

Comment: I must admit I'm a bit confused - which code is in which Activity? If this is in the calling/parent Activity, what's in the child one? because you'll certainly need to return an Intent from it with setResult(int resultCode, Intent  data). Could you post the code in your RoleList class too?

Comment: //ProjectList.java 
   projectID and castingTimeSlotID  are long variables having some value

        Intent i = new Intent(ProjectList.this,RoleList.class);
 Bundle c = new Bundle();            
 c.putLong("PID", projectID );
 c.putLong("CTSID", castingTimeSlotID);
 i.putExtras(c);
 startActivityForResult(i,0);

//RoleList.java 
         public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,          Intent data) {
  Bundle c = new Bundle();
         c = data.getExtras();
     projectID = c.getLong("PID",projectID);
     castingTimeSlotID = c.getLong("CTSID");
 }

this  returns null

Answer (score 1):

hey buddy  i got the answer today

1 st  activity on click

```
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(ProjectList.this,RoleList.class);
     myIntent.putExtra("key", variable);
     myIntent.putExtra("key", variable);
     startActivity(myIntent);
     finish();
```

2 nd activity on Create

```
    Intent myIntent = getIntent(); // this is just for example purpose
    myIntent.getExtras();
    PID = myIntent.getLongExtra("key", variable);
    CID = myIntent.getLongExtra("key", variable);
```

thats it working fine